# History.js causes infinite loop after four pushStates

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I'm learning History.js and I stumbled upon a problem. I use this function to load content into block:

```
loadPost: function(article) {
        Functions.foldAllBlocks();

        var url = article.attr('data-url'),
            content = article.find('.entry'),
            oldText = content.text(),
            blockPosition = article.offset().top,
            postTitle = article.find('h2').text();

        if(article.hasClass('expand')) {
            article.attr('data-entry',oldText);

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                article.addClass('collapse').removeClass('expand');

                var entry = $(data).find('.entry > *');
                content.html(entry);

                Functions.orderBlocks();

                Functions.maintainHistory(postTitle, url);

                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: blockPosition
                },200);
            });
        } else {
            article.addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse');

            content.text(article.attr('data-entry'));

            Functions.orderBlocks();

            Functions.maintainHistory(baseSitename, baseURL);

            $('body, html').animate({
                scrollTop: blockPosition
            },500);
        }
    }
```

and this to maintain my history state:

```
maintainHistory: function(title, url){
        (function(window, undefined) {
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
                var State = History.getState(),
                    cleanUrl = State.cleanUrl;

                if(cleanUrl === baseURL) {
                    Functions.foldAllBlocks();
                } else {
                    var article = $('h2 a[href="'+cleanUrl+'"]').closest('article');

                    Functions.loadPost(article);
                }
            });

            History.pushState({ page: title }, title, url);
        })(window);
    }
```

There two functions are the only one using History.js. My problem is - every time, after fourth click (and thus, forth `loadPost` and `maintainHistory` firing) browser is getting stuck between last two articles.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score -1):

Your `maintainHistory` function could use a minor rewrite.  The way you have it now, the History.Adaptor will get stacked up with "statechange" handlers.  Binding your event should only take place once, not every time you call the method.  Try this:

```
    maintainHistory: (function(window, undefined) {
        console.log("Binding 'statechange' event - this should only happen once");
        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
            console.log("window.statechange event fired!");
            var State = History.getState(),
                cleanUrl = State.cleanUrl;

            if(cleanUrl === baseURL) {
                Functions.foldAllBlocks();
            } else {
                var article = $('h2 a[href="'+cleanUrl+'"]').closest('article');

                Functions.loadPost(article);
            }
        });

        // This is the function that is bound to maintainHistory
        // The wrapping function is self-executing, will only happen once, and 
        // creates a nice little closure for binding the "statechange" event
        return function(title, url) {
            console.log("maintainHistory was called with title", title, "and url", url);
            History.pushState({ page: title }, title, url);
        };

    })(window),

    nextPropertyInFunctions: function() { ...}
```

Comment: `title` and `url` parameters from `maintainHistory: function(title, url)` aren't being passed to `return function(title, url)`.

Comment: did you try the code?  What is happening is the self-executing function will execute immediately, and it returns the inner function.  The final result is `maintainHistory: function(title, url) { ... }`

Comment: Yes I did, that's why I'm replying ;-) The problem is, the function isn't actually even going inside `History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {`. I placed an `alert()` there and it didn't fire.

Comment: And I did wronte another one, `return function() { alert('a'); }; and it didn't fire either. I think placing a function inside is a problem.

Comment: Also (sorry for the third comment) please note that those functions are inside an object called `Functions` (as you can see by looking at firing of `Functions.loadPost(article)`).

Comment: Don't use alerts (if you want to call yourself a js developer ;) - I added some logging statements - take note of the comma after the self-executing function.  The technique I used in my answer is something I do all the time, so I know it works.  There is an error somewhere else and I can't see it unless you post some example code on jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Console returns `Binding 'statechange' event - this should only happen once` and then... everythig stops. Everything else (when I comment out your function) works great, so it's most unlikely that the rest of the code is faulty.

Comment: And `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined ` from `History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {`...

Comment: Ah, see, there's your error.  History.Adaptor is not defined yet.  You need to fix that on your own.  Make sure History is loaded before your Functions file is loaded.  If you want to be lazy (and write buggy code) you can wrap the bind() block in a timeout... about 500ms should be enough (not recommended).  You you want to write good code, check out requirejs - to load all of your dependencies... it's a must-have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62994/discussion-between-ryan-wheale-and-tomek-buszewski).

Comment: Grrr- wandering down voter.  At least give an insult to this injury!